# Java single dimention arrays equating two variables of different size

Tags: java

```
class myArray{

    public static void main(String args []){

    int x[]={2,3};
    int y[]={4,5,6};
    System.out.println(x);/*gives something like [I@5445a*/
    System.out.println(y);/*[I@5442c */
    x=y;
    System.out.println(x); /*gives same as that of y (i.e [I@5442c  ). What does happen  here?*/
    System.out.println(x[2]);/* gives 6*/
    }
}
```

> But what does happen when we use "x=y" ?Does address of y goes to x or something else?Is this garbage value?

Comment: *"But what does happen when we use "x=y" ?"* what happened if when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array variables are also references just like a class-typed variable. So x and y contain only references to an array somewhere in memory. Let's look at that assignment:

> But what does happen when we use "x=y" ?

Yes, just like with objects in java, the address to the array y is stored in x. The result is that x and y reference the same array and the array previously referenced by x is lost (and eventually garbage collected). If you instead want a copy of y to be assigned to x try:

```
x = Arrays.copyOf(y, y.length)
```

A tip: Try using the following code if you want to print the contents of an array:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

For more info about the Arrays class try: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Then what does this mean [I@5445a.
This is not in hexadecimal,so how can you say that this is address?
I know [ -> means array
I - int
but what about @ 
and other values.

Comment: The @ sign separates the "address" from the first part that I'm not entirely sure what it's supposed to look like. I'm rather sure that "5545a" is some kind of address but not necessarily referring to an actual hardware address. Maybe it's implementation defined. I'll have to check the java specs.

Comment: Turns out that the [I part is the "class" name for an int[] as you said @RishabhGoyal.

See ["Class Objects for Arrays"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8).

Comment: Thnx a lot dude I got it

Comment: `5545a` is the hashcode of the array object. its not a hardware address. The value gets converted into actual heap address the time array is going to be used in the program.

Comment: And `@` is just a signification of `at`

Answer (score 2):

> But what does happen when we use "x=y" ?

The array referred to by `y` also then becomes referenced by `x`, making the array originally referenced by `x` eligible for garbage collection (since it isn't referenced anywhere else in this example.)

Comment: so you mean that in the above program when we use "x=y" then all address of y is copied to x.And previous value and address of x is now eligible for garbage collection...

Comment: @RishabhGoyal Yes, but note that the previous object referred to by `x` is only eligible for garbage collection because it's not referred to elsewhere.

Comment: even I think the same.
But one of my friend claims that this is not address bcz we down have pointer in java :(
This was making me confused.
Thnx berry!!

Answer (score 0):

**Lets understand `Value / Reference and assignments` in java:**

**1)** This code gives you ***value reference pointer*** to ***heap address*** of the Arrays `X` and `Y`. Which simply means ***memory address*** of X and Y. Because Array are objects and Java Objects hold address pointers and not real values.

```
System.out.println(x);/*gives something like [I@5445a*/
System.out.println(y)
```

**2)** This code `x=y` assigns `Y`'s heap address to `X`. Now X and Y both points to same address in the heap. This is called ***reference assignment***.

**3)** This line `System.out.println(x)` will print the same address as `Y` has. Refer ***Point#2***

**4)** This line `System.out.println(x[2])` gives you the value of the element inside the Array. Element is integer. Integer is primitive data type in Java. And primitive data types hold ***real value*** and not address in the heap.

**Answer Updated:**

**1)** `[I@5445a` represents *symbolic reference* of Array object in the heap.

**2)** `[` means Number of array dimensions. (1 dimension)

**3)** `I` means type of array. (int)

**4)** `@5445a` is the integer hashcode of Array Object. Which then gets converted into actual reference in the heap. And don't assume the actual address to be Hex, it can be in other formats too. This depends on individual JVM implementation. Its vendor specific.

Comment: Then what does this mean [I@5445a.
This is not in hexadecimal,so how can you say that this is address?
I know [ -> means array
I - int
but what about @ 
and other values.